# Unable to uncomment just the cron by matching the string MYAPP

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cron, syntax

Below is my existing cron which i wish to enable

```
crontab -l

####Cron to auto restart MYAPP
###*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/cron.out
```

I wish to enable cron by matching app name `MYAPP`

I use the below `sed` command for the same:

```
crontab -l> /web/playbooks/cronenabledisable/wladmin.cron
sed -i '/^#.*MYAPP/Is/^[#]*//' /web/playbooks/cronenabledisable/wladmin.cron
crontab /web/playbooks/cronenabledisable/wladmin.cron
```

Unfortunately, it uncomments the comment section i.e. `####Cron to auto restart MYAPP` failing the cron to get installed.

Problematic Current Output:

```
Cron to auto restart MYAPP
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/cron.out
```

Expected Output:

```
####Cron to auto restart MYAPP
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/cron.out
```

Note: i wish to keep `MYAPP` in the comment section i.e `####Cron to auto restart MYAPP` and i cannot simply remove it for the sake of naming conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ei.bak '/#+(\*.*myapp)/Is//\1/' input_file
####Cron to auto restart MYAPP
*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/cron.out
```

`-i.bak` will create a backup file in case you need to roll back

Answer (score 0):

First off, a suggestion: DO NOT USE the "-i" option of the GNU-sed! It is dangerous. It purports to do an "inline edit" of the file, but in fact it is just an automated edit-to-a-temporary-file-and-replace-the-original. This means, it might change the owner or the group, it will definitely change the inode number and other meta information and - unlike using standard methods - you have no control over the temporary file it uses. This can turn out to be problematic when the system crashes at the right (wrong) moment. It might not be your problem, but it is not supported by POSIX either and therefore not portable.

Instead, do it like it is done with any standards-adhering `sed` since the beginning of time (Midnight, Jan 1st 1970, LOL):

```
if sed '.....' /your/file > /path/to/tmpfile ; then
     mv /your/file /your/file.bak    # optional, create backup
     mv /path/to/tmpfile /your/file
     chown .....        # optionally adjust rights/ownership
     chmod .....
fi
```

Now to your problem: it is a wrong regular expression:

```
/^#.*MYAPP/
```

Here you look for *beginning of line, followed by a "#", followed by any number of any characters, followed by "MYAPP"*. sed will always use "longest match" (also called "greedy"), which means: if it sees any line, starting with an octothorpe and the string "MYAPP" anywhere, it will be a match. This is true for this line:

```
###*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/cron.out
```

But also this one:

```
####Cron to auto restart MYAPP
```

If your sample crontab is significant your commented codelines only have 3 octothorpes in front, but comments have 4, so a solution could be (only the relevant sed-code):

```
/^###[^#].*MYAPP/ s/^###//
```

This operates only on lines with exactly 3 octothorpes at the beginning of a line (3 octothorpes followed by a non-octothorpe, "[^#]" matches anything but a "#"), followed by "MYAPP" anywhere in the line. On such lines the first 3 octothorpes are replaced by nothing (that is: deleted).

Comment: i have no control over the number of hash `#` in either of the below 2 lines of cron `line 1: ####Cron to auto restart MYAPP
line 2: #######*/15 * * * * ansible-playbook  /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/va_action.yml | tee -a /web/playbooks/detectMYAPP/cron.out` However, what i can do is to have the first line that should remain commented start with application name right after the hash `#` like this `#### MYAPP Cron to auto restart` and then uncomment the line matching `MYAPP` but not right after the starting hash `##`